# How to Optimize Search Result from address book in iphone

Tags: iphone, addressbook

When ever user search for anything like name , phone number , url, email addres then I want to  search that query against address book data. My solution is working fine but it is slow . If address book data is huge , app gets stuck. How can I optimize the search , so that my application won't hang even in large address book data?

**EDIT 1 Here is my code**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self takeSomeActionWhenTextChange];  
}

-(void)takeSomeActionWhenTextChange{
    [contactArray removeAllObjects];
    NSString *searchText=[[textSearchBar text] lowercaseString];


    for (int index=0; index<count; index++) {
        ABRecordRef record=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, index);
        //[self checkStringISAddress:searchText withRecord:record];
        if ([self checkStringIsFirstName:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsLastName:searchText withRecord:record] == YES
        ||[self checkStringIsNote:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsAddress:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsCompany:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        ||[self checkStringIsEmail:searchText withRecord:record]
        ||[self checkStringIsPhonenumber:searchText withRecord:record]==YES )
        {
            NSLog(@"object added inside Array");
            [contactArray addObject:record];
            [contactTableView reloadData];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"No Match For this object");
            [contactTableView reloadData];

        }

    }

}
```

I will check if substring from search query matches with first name, last name , email & so on. Above methods contain logic to check if substring is present or not? If ti matches , i will add it to array else not.

SHOULD I USE THREAD OR GCD TO PERFOEM SEARCH ? IF YES , HOW? HOW CAN I UPDATE MY TABLE VIEW?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have one that maybe help you

1.Get all contacts

```
NSArray *thePeoples = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

2.Create another array(records) from the contacts array(thePeoples)

```
records:{name:"abc", number:"123", url:"url", email:"email"}
```

3.Search the mutableArray(records) with predicate

```
NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"record.phoneNumber contains %@",string];

NSArray * filteredArray = [records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
```

Hope it'll help you

Comment: My solution works but it is slow for huge data. So how can I optimize the search ? Also user can enter anything like email or name or phone number. then I will search accordingly in addressbook

Comment: Can you show me your solution?? I don't know what's wrong if there's no code

Comment: It must be slow because you are checking it manually..Try using NSPredicate, it will go faster

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I use NSPredicate ? As shown in your code , you have used PredicateWithFormat:@"record.phoneNumber. I want to search in name,ph no,email, notes,company,address. If my search query matches with any of the property,I want to show that record in table view

Comment: Yes, you must do it manually with "if". NSPredicate can only search for one property.